# To find the imaginary part of an analytic function whose real part is given

Tags: complex-analysis

let $u(x,y)=2x(1-y)$ for all real $x$ and $y$ .Find $v(x,y)$ such that $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y) $ is analytic

The options are

(a)$x^2-(y-1)^2$

(b)$(x-1)^2-y^2$

(c)$(x-1)^2+y^2$

(d)$x^2+(y-1)^2$

> I've applied Milne Thomson method and I got $f(z)=2z+iz^2$
>    after substituting $z=x+iy$ $f(x,y)=2x(1-y)+i(x^2-y^2+2y)$ . So the real part becomes true but imaginary part does not become match with any options. Where I have done the  mistake?

Comment: No, two of them are harmonic.

Comment: Actually you don't know $f$ has that exact form; don't forget you can add any constant.

Comment: $x^2-y^2+2y=x^2-(y-1)^2\color{#C00}{+1}$. The imaginary part is known modulo a constant.

Answer (score 3):

Try the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: :But Sir, Could u plz explain Why can't we apply Milne Thomson method here ?

Comment: I didn't say you can't.  Actually I don't know the Milne Thomson method, and don't have an exposition of it at hand.  Do you have a link?

Comment: For the Milne-Thomson method, see http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0036144503432151.

Answer (score 0):

The Thing is that you have calculated f(z) correctly but ignored the constant of integration that comes.
Your evaluated f(z) is $$f(z)=2z+iz^2+C$$
now look at V(x,y).
$$V(x,y)=x^2-y^2+2y$$
Subtract 1 to complete the square of y.
you get
$$V(x,y)=x^2-y^2+2y-1$$
$$V(x,y)=x^2-(y-1)^2$$
Now, how to account for the extra +1 you ask?
The constant of integration!Thus, $$C=-i1$$
$$f(z)=2z+iz^2-i$$